# Inject objective c into UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, forms

I have made a login form in html/javascript to be injected into a UIWebView in my iPhone application. This all works really well and the login works. But when I press the login button it goes to the expected page within that view.

I was wondering if I could inject some objective c or by ways of a javascript do a modalView or dismissView to have upon the login have the page go to the application.

In the Application I have just made the UI of the webpage more user friendly.

So to kind of show what I am asking I have pasted some code.

```
NSString *myHTML = @"<form action="gotowebsite.com" onSubmit='return !validateLogin();'><input some textfield><input password field>";
```

Now I am imagining that the dismissal code will go into the onSubmit area.

Am I on a possibly good track??

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `UIWebViewDelegate` in your class and on successful login redirect your page to a url like login://success
when you redirect your page, UIWebview will start loading request and the call the function written below.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.
          NSURL *url = [request URL];
          NSString *urlStr =   [url absoluteString];

          if([urlStr isEqualToString:@"login://success"]){ //same url which you gave for redirection
             [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // or do whatever you want to do on a successful login
          }

          return YES;   
}
```

Comment: ok I think I am on the right track as I understand what you are telling me - however I am not sure how to link up the action="" command (where the form is linked to upon succession) to the isEqualToString command. It is not picking it up.

Comment: As your are submitting your form to "gotowebsite.com" after validation. Similarly, when your form will send data to url (action) and on server/(action) there is mechanism to authenticate user and when this is done, simply redirect after successful authentication to url (login://success)